# Xilinx - Vivado Project: VGA IO not working

Tags: sdk, vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I'm new to Xilinx-Vivado. So at the moment we just need to look and see how Vivado and SDK work using Zybo Zynq-7000 Board. I searched on the internet, and found a project with VGA IO. The mysterious thing is that I actually made it to work when I was at school, but due to the current situation, we are not able to get much help, I am now alone with it at home.

[This](https://www.instructables.com/Zybo-Game-Console/) is the project.

Firstly I'd like to ask what does the console below tell me?

1. I generated the bitstream, and then exported the hardware included the bitstream, lastly I launch SDK. On SDK i programmed the FPGA and then ran the project as Launch as Hardware (System debugger and GDB).
   That's how I did it:
   [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwrkS.png/)
2. And the configuartions:
   [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI92E.png/)
3. And the output I am getting through the console is:
   [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1T60.png/)

**To my main problem**, it is that I have connected all the cables to the Zybo Board that is required; USB cable from my laptop to the FPGA and VGA cable from the FPGA up to my monitor screen. The problem is that I am not getting any output on my monitor, do I have to enable something so that my VGA cable from FPGA to monitor is working?

Comment: You say something doesn't work, but you don't tell what isn't working.  What do you expect to happen and what are you observing instead.  Does the design not program? Does the design program but you get no output?

As for the console, there is no error.  It's just saying that nothing has changed since you last built so it doesn't need to to be rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks for explaning that. My problem is that my VGA/output is not showing on my Monitor, the design programs but I get no output through the VGA. Do I have to enable something to get it to work?

Comment: @Travis Thanks, I've edited my question, As you said, I am not getting any output to my monitor.

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately boils down to standard debugging.  I can only give a couple suggestions.

First, confirm that your design is working in simulation; check that your outputs, especially your sync signals, are working as expected.

Next confirm that your IO constraints are set up correctly and that you are using the right IO pins on the board.

If those all seem correct, ideally you'd have access to a signal analyzer, but that sounds unlikely in current circumstances.  As an alternative, you can look at using an ILA, like chipscope, to probe the signals and see monitor them in hardware.

Last, and obviously, make sure all of the cables are connected correctly.

Good luck with the design.

Comment: Also would it make a difference, because my monitor does not have VGA and I am using a converter, I just got told that it would not make any difference if it is a converter and not a cable (VGA to HDMI). Is that right?

Comment: The the connection is VGA coming out of the FPGA and then a converter is connected to the VGA cable, I presume that should work fine.  If the FPGA output is HDMI, then it probably won't work.

Comment: No, it's a VGA cable with a converter to the monitor.

Comment: I've done your suggestions, but couldn't get it to work. Could it be the monitor? Could there be a difference on the monitors? By the way, do you know how I can find the Video timing of the Zybo?